# Registry.GetValue automatically expands environment variables - any way to avoid that?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

When using `Registry.GetValue(key, name, null)`, instead of:

```
C:\Windows\system32
```

I would like to retrieve the raw registry entry:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32
```

This is possible in C with WinAPI, but I don't see a way to do that with .NET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass it `RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames`. For example:

```
var key = @"SOFTWARE\Classes\.library-ms\ShellNew";
var name = "IconPath";

var regval = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key).GetValue(name, "",
RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);

Console.WriteLine(regval);
```

output is: 
%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-1001

Comment: `Registry.GetValue` doesn't seem to have this overload, but it looks like `RegistryKey.GetValue` does - I haven't noticed this one before, I will try it in a second.

Comment: @Adrian17 you are correct. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it does what you want by default:

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\dummy", "pathTest", @"%SystemRoot%\system32");
Console.WriteLine(Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\dummy", "pathTest", null));

// Output:
// %SystemRoot%\system32
```

Comment: try:

    `const string systemPath = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment";

    var result = Registry.GetValue(systemPath, "path", null) as string; 
    Console.WriteLine(result)`;

Comment: Ok, tried it. But, on my machine at least, the data in that key/value does not have any environment variables in it - they are already expanded in the reg key. Seems like your question should be re-worded to include "for registry keys with `Type=REG_EXPAND_SZ`", but seems like you got your answer, so it's all good.